# Sort() not working correctly in Python for Dict

Tags: python, sorting, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file with many columns. I am trying to sort the rows based on the value in one of the columns (in descending numerical order). And I only wnat it to output the top 10. However, when I use the following code, I get an incorrect output.

```
import csv
f = open('SNPs.csv', "rU")
reader = csv.reader(f)
output = [row for row in reader]
output.sort(key=lambda x: x[32], reverse=True)
print dict((row[10], (row[11], row[8], row[32])) for row in output[:10])
```

The output looks something like:

```
'XRgroup8': ('38', '2', '0.47'), '2': ('30', '13', '0.37'), 'Chromosome': ('Position', 'Distance', 'GC'), 'XRgroup5': ('54', '1', '0.45')
```

So clearly it isn't returning 10 values and they aren't in order. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `len(output)`? What final output are you hoping for?

Comment: You could just do `output = list(reader)`, or even better, `output = sorted(reader, key= ..., reverse=True)`

Comment: @mgilson yes, that works, however, can I do that while still only outputting those certain columns? (10, 11, 8, 32)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to know:
Python's dicts are unordered, and therefor cannot be sorted.

If you need a dict that maintains the order, check out http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

The second thing:

A dict's keys are unique.
If you try to add a key that is already in the dict, the value will be overwritten.
This is the most likely reason you're not getting all the elements you were hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

The `output` list is sorted but the dictionaries are orderless, this is why you can see no order in the resulting dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting *strings* (which are ordered *lexicographically*) but expecting them to be sorted in *numerical order*.  That's not going to happen.  You probably want to change your sorting `key` function to something like: `lambda x: float(x[32])` so that you'll be sorting based on floats which sort *numerically*.

---

Note also that the dictionary won't preserve any of that order (you could use a `collections.OrderedDict` instead -- but I assume you already knew that).

Comment: When I try to convert to float, It returns a ValueError "Could not convert string to float"

Comment: @gr8skillz -- Then your string has something in it that can't be converted to a float -- Perhaps your datafile is corrupt?  Try to figure out what the value of the string is that can't be converted and it might shed some light on why you're getting that error

Comment: just realized it was the headers for my columns. Whoops.

Comment: @gr8skillz -- You'll get an error on the line which produces `'Chromosome': ('Position', 'Distance', 'GC')`  -- `'GC'` can't be converted to a float.

Answer (score 0):

The moment you run

```
print dict((row[10], (row[11], row[8], row[32])) for row in output[:10])
```

you have converted your sorted output (`output.sort(...)`) to an orderless dictionary, and a dictionary is essentially implemented as a hash table in Python.  For detailed explanation - http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2000-March/048085.html